# Increase the space between the image and the text

Tags: html, css

How do I increase the space between the image and the div? I have to display some text in the div from an object. The image is in one tag, and text will be in the div tag beside the image.

```html
<div>
  <div id="top">
    <img src="" id="toppopupimage" hspace="50" style="width:85px;height:90px;float:left;background-color:white;">
    <div id="text" class="externaltext"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry Kishan. I have checked both of your answers. I couldn't find your code and even there is no option or button to mark your answer as the correct one. I mean the right symbol, which becomes green when we click it becomes green in color.

Comment: @YashwanthBeeravelli What's with the constant accept/unaccept going on?

Comment: @YashwanthBeeravelli now i think you see my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add `margin` and `float` to your `#text` div:

```css
#text {
    margin-left: 15px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="top" >
      <img src="" id="toppopupimage" hspace="50" style="width:85px;height:90px;float:left;background-color:white;">
      <div id="text" class="externaltext">Text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Another way is to remove float from your image and set `display: inline-block;` on the elements:

```css
img {
    width: 85px;
    height: 90px;
    background: white;
    display: inline-block;
}

img + div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="top" >
      <img src="" id="toppopupimage" hspace="50" >
      <div id="text" class="externaltext">Text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you give example of you second suggestion

Comment: you first answer same as my answer. you edit you answer after i give my answer.so you don't deserve 2 upvote

Comment: @Kishan My answer is more complete and earlier than yours. Don't be so petty.

Answer (score 2):

Just apply the margin on img tag or the div:

```
#top img{
   margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could uss a css rule and add a margin to the image or the text div.

```css
#text {
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="top">
    <img src="" id="toppopupimage" hspace="50" style="width:85px;height:90px;float:left;background-color:white;">
    <div id="text" class="externaltext">
      SOME TEXT HERE
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `margin-right` for the img or `margin-left` for the text. Either way it will work.

```css
#top img {
  margin-right: 55px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="top">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/85x90" id="toppopupimage" hspace="20" style="width:85px;height:90px;float:left;background-color:white;">
    <div id="text" class="externaltext">
      I am separated from the image by 55px
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

first you set float left for your text div then you give margin because you div having full width for parent div

```css
#text {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="top">
    <img src="" id="toppopupimage" hspace="50" style="width:85px;height:90px;float:left;background-color:white;">
    <div id="text" class="externaltext">
      SOME TEXT HERE
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

output

[image]